# Async JAX-RS in JBoss

Tags: java, asynchronous, jboss, jax-rs

I am trying to implement async jax rs. I am using the code like below:

```
public void isAlive(@Suspended AsyncResponse ar)
```

For this, I have also added a jar - jaxrs-ri-2.29.1.jar

Now, when I run start jboss, it gives me the following error:

```
JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sounds more like it has something to do with your configuration.

Comment: In addition to what @PaulSamsotha said. You also shouldn't need to add any libraries to your deployment to get JAX-RS to work.